# Unexpected results running update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am running a simple update statement to update all records in my table. 
Update Table_A
Set Field_Name = "Yes";

I am running this intentionally without a Where clause. When the statement runs not all of the records update -- Any of the records with the Client_ID "ABC" do not update. If I modify the query to include:
WHERE Client_ID = "ABC" the records update. Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: _" Any idea what is causing this?"_ isn't really a question. Do you have a trigger(s) on the table or something you don't tell us about it?

Comment: My question is why would an update statement with no where clause not update an entire table?